# Why am I in an endless loop when using LIKE in Access VBA query

Tags: ms-access

I am using openrecordset to do a select query but I want the query to look for a specific word within a column and only return those records.

I tried different styles and it seems I keep getting the same type of error:
runtime error 6: overflow. that is because of a counter that I have, which an integer can only hold no more that 32,000 bytes.

If I remove the counter, It because an endless loop, no error messages just stuff running in the background. I have to restart access.

```
'Variables
Dim counter As Integer

'DB variables
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb

'Get records query
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Price_List WHERE Description LIKE '*cabin*'")

'Determine if the specified valve for this project was found
If rs.EOF Then
    MsgBox "No records were found for enclosures." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "You can contact someone", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "No Records Found"
    End
End If

List10.RowSource = ""

'display
List10.ColumnCount = 5
List10.ColumnWidths = "1500;4000;1200;1200;1200" 'Setting column widths for each record

counter = 0
Do
    If counter = 0 Then
        List10.AddItem ("Part Number)
        List10.AddItem (rs!PartNumber)
    Else
        List10.AddItem (rs!PartNumber)
    End If

    'counter = counter + 1
Loop Until rs.EOF

Label14.Caption = rs.RecordCount

rs.Close
db.Close
```

I expect it to return at least 5 records but I guess it's returning way more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues.

First of all, there is no guarantee the cursor will be the first record so you have to use

```
If rs.EOF AND rs.BOF
```

to check for no records returned.

You then have to start with

```
rs.MoveFirst
```

to go to the first record and then in your loop you need

```
rs.MoveNext
```

to move to the next record and so on

Your current code just infinitely runs on the one record the recordset happens to open in.

Answer (score 0):

After you checked for `rs.EOF`, you need to put the cursor on the first record and add to your list the title `"Part Number"` so you don't need `if` inside the loop.
After that start the loop and at the end of each iteration move to the next record:

```
rs.MoveFirst
List10.AddItem ("Part Number")
Do
    List10.AddItem (rs!PartNumber)
    counter = counter + 1
    rs.MoveNext
Loop Until rs.EOF
```

Comment: If statement inside the do until loop is for having a title inside the list box. In the end i forgot to put rs.movenext

Comment: You can add the title once before the loop and then you don't need the if statement.